# Java Nested loop to print numbers in a descending triangle

Tags: java, loops

I have to write a nested loop fragment that will have the following output:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Numbers have to be in that exact order, i'm trying to use for loops but I can't really figure out how to remove the repeating numbers.

How would I achieve this using nested loops?

The output i'm currently getting looks like:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

etc.

Comment: any code examples?

Comment: How do I add a well formatted code? I don't use this site often sorry!

Comment: show us your code please !

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I just figured it out!

```
int x = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an external count, not base the value you're printing out on j. Thus increase the count in the nested loop every time and print that value.

Answer (score 0):

Write a code something like below. I didn't check the syntax, that is the work for you.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < k; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
       System.out.print(j + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```